# While statement and expressions

Tags: python, while-loop

`while` loop statement gets executed as long as the expression is true.

After the 10th time, the pop() throws an IndexError back because there are 10 elements in the list. But, the below code executes fine without any error. Why is it so?

```
a = [x*x for x in range(10)]
while a.pop():
    print("elements in the list")
```

It might be a very basic question, but I am trying to get comfortable with Python.

Comment: It works as you expect for me.

Comment: I don't know this for sure but maybe the while-loop is treating the exception as false? I would love to find out too.

Comment: @dawg I am using anaconda/3.5.2/pycharm. I tried it again and it works without any error..

Comment: @SSNR looks like while doesn't handle the StopIteration while `for` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After the 10th time, the pop() throws an IndexError back because there are 10 elements in the list.

No, the code never tries to do any `pop`s after the 10th, because the 10th `pop` returns `0`. `0` is considered false in a boolean context, so the loop terminates at that point.

Comment: It's the zero! I thought it was some kind of magic that the `while-loop` uses to handle exceptions.

Comment: That was quick :) I changed to range(2,10) and as you mentioned I do get IndexError back. Looks like `for` handles the StopIteration and `while` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear what your issue is. If I execute your code, it does (what I think) you expect. It is likely the `0` that is causing unexpected behavior:

```
>>> a = [x*x for x in range(10)]
>>> while a.pop():
...    print a
... 
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
[0, 1, 4, 9]
[0, 1, 4]
[0, 1]
[0]
```

It is more *Pythonic* to test the list itself only rather than the result of `.pop()` since that will terminate the loop on any falsy item:

```
>>> li=[1,2,3,False,4,5]
>>> while li.pop():
...    print li
... 
[1, 2, 3, False, 4]
[1, 2, 3, False]
```

You can see that the `while` loop is terminated as it encounters `False` from pop.

It would be more typical to do:

```
>>> li=[1,2,3,False,4,5]
>>> while li:
...    e=li.pop()
...    print e, li
... 
5 [1, 2, 3, False, 4]
4 [1, 2, 3, False]
False [1, 2, 3]
3 [1, 2]
2 [1]
1 []
```

which terminates when the list becomes false.

Better still (in Python) to use a `for` loop which is non destructive to the list:

```
>>> li=[1,2,3,False,4,5]
>>> for e in li:
...    print e, li
... 
1 [1, 2, 3, False, 4, 5]
2 [1, 2, 3, False, 4, 5]
3 [1, 2, 3, False, 4, 5]
False [1, 2, 3, False, 4, 5]
4 [1, 2, 3, False, 4, 5]
5 [1, 2, 3, False, 4, 5]
```